# load data from S3 to Snowflake, with lambda invocation in a sequential order 1 by 1

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to load data from my S3 bucket folder to snowflake table using lambda. I have setup an S3 trigger where my files are getting ingested and formed an integration between lambda and to snowflake to load the incoming file into my s3 to snowflake table.

The problem is there are 1000 of files getting ingested to my S3 folder and is forming congestion between my snowflake and lambda. What I'm looking for is a way where when 1000 of files are getting ingestd to my S3 bucket, the lambda shouls process one file at a time. Once the first file is loaded, then only it processes the next file in a sequential order. For eg: either recieving an acknowledgement from snowflake or on its on.

Comment: Why are you using lambda when Snowflake can load data directly from S3 much more efficiently?

Comment: I have all my data in S3, I'm building an automation service, ehatever latest data comes in gets loaded to snowflake tabnle

Comment: OK - but Snowflake can handle all this as part of it's COPY INTO process (or via Snowpipe if you want to run continuously rather than to a schedule) so I'm not sure why you are re-inventing the wheel by writing lambda functions to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the AWS Lambda function to have [Reserved concurrency - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html):

> This represents the maximum number of concurrent instances allocated to your function.

By setting `Reserved Concurrency = 1`, only one instance of the Lambda function will run at a time. Depending upon your Snowflake configuration, you might choose to increase this to 2 or 3 to process files faster without overwhelming Snowflake.

You can also configure the **Batch Size**, which is the maximum number of events that will be passed to the function. If S3 sends more than one file to the same Lambda instance, your code can loop through the events and process multiple files per invocation.

I'm just *slightly* worried that if, you have a large number of objects being created and the Lambda function is being throttled by a concurrency of 1, the invocations of Lambda by S3 **might cause timeouts after multiple retries**. If so, you should:

- Configure S3 to send the events to an **Amazon SQS queue** (instead of directly to the Lambda function), and
- Configure Lambda to **pull messages from the SQS queue**

This way, the messages will queue-up safely instead of (potentially) timing-out due to a large backlog of files.

Comment: Thanks, I had just tested with setting the concurrency to 1, and for now it works well without any issue, Will probably see to set SQS as a medium Thanks again

Comment: If the concurrency is 1, and at a stage my lambda is not able to process that file after multiple retries, will it going to skip that file and move to other?  @John Rotenstein

Comment: There are two scenarios... One is that your Lambda function returns an error because its code failed in some way (eg bad format file, or exceeded the timeout). For such situations, the Lambda will keep retrying, but you want to activate a Dead Letter Queue to 'capture' the bad messages after a few retries. This differs to what I was describing _might_ happen, which is if the single Lambda function is taking too long processing all the messages, then the S3 invocation might get upset. I'm not 100% sure whether that would happen, but wanted to mention it in case something strange happens.

Comment: Alright, thank-you so much. I'll have a look in it while testing.